# Magento 2 rest API returns false when trying to get a token

Tags: magento2, php, api, rest-api, curl

I am trying to create a web app that gets data from a Magento 2 website thanks to the API, following [this tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-api/) but it returns `bool(false)` when I do `var_dump($token)`

I have read other threads on StackOverflow saying [it might be linked to an error with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44226541/php-curl-rest-api-token-return-false-magento-2), but I have no error when I use `curl_error($ch)` so I don't think that's the issue.

My code :

```
  $userData = array("username" => $username, "password" => $password); 
  $ch = curl_init("http://mywebsite/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token"); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData)); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Length: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

  $token = curl_exec($ch);
```

Thank you for reading.

EDIT: The account I use has a role with all permission so that shouldn't be the issue either.

EDIT 2: When I change the Magento URL and account to the ones from [this demo](https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/magento-2-demo-sample-data-admin-access/) it returns me a token and the information I want, but not with the Magento I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this code which is quite similar:

```
//API URL
$url = 'http://mywebsite/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';

//create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init($url);

//setup request to send json via POST
$data = array(
    'username' => '.....',
    'password' => '.....'
);
$payload = json_encode(array("user" => $data));

//attach encoded JSON string to the POST fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

//set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

//return response instead of outputting
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute the POST request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close cURL resource
curl_close($ch);
```

You can try also to follow the redirect :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

You can also add these lines in order to debug your CURL request in a custom file.

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$verbose = fopen('/tmp/curl.log', 'w+');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
```

Moreover, first try to test you API thanks to Postman or other software to know if the problem is on the curl / php side.

What is your webserver ? Apache / Nginx ? Do you use the default Magento 2 configuration ?

Comment: It's Nginx I think and I don't know much about the Magento2 configuration as I just started working on this project today.

I managed to find that it isn't an issue with my code, as when I try to use it with another Magento 2 it works (I found [this demo](https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/magento-2-demo-sample-data-admin-access/) which does return the token)

Comment: I started working on this project today but it was started by someone else, that's why I said that ^^

Comment: Did you try to retrieve the token with Postman ?

Comment: I do get the token for the website with Postman, but not with my code. Even though the exact same code with the demo I linked earlier works perfectly.

(Also, you just taught me what Postman was and it is very nice indeed, thanks :) )

Comment: Can you check to add the verbose and check the log ?

Comment: You can also check the apache/nginx/magento logs and compare with the postman request.

Comment: Well, I had a day off after the week end, and a coworker made it work. The thing is, none of us understands why it works now. It's the exact same code, he simply created functions and some things like that, but the code itself (the cURL bits) didn't change at all. 

This seems to be happenning a lot with magento ^^

Comment: Strange, there is a root cause but we do not see it.